# Magento 2 on login getting message This website is excluded from customer's group

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created one group from admin then assign that group to the specific customer. Now whenever I am trying to log in with that customer getting message "This website is excluded from customer's group.".

I have found this exception is throwing from the observer `vendor/magento/module-customer/Observer/CustomerGroupAuthenticate.php`. And my group entry is in the database table customer_group_excluded_website

Can you please tell me is there any configuration in magento admin from where we can add specific groups into this table customer_group_excluded_website ?

Thank You!

Abbas

Answer (score 4):

If you go to

> Admin Panel -> Customers -> Customer Groups -> [ Select your customer
> related group ] -> Excluded Website(s)

Make sure the website from where you are trying to login with this customer group should not be selected in Excluded Website(s)

I hope if will helpful for anyone else. :)